# Validate datetime in Symfony2

Tags: validation, symfony

I am trying to validate a posted datetime string but always getting the generic error
"ERROR: This value is not valid". Data are posted on a restful api (if that makes any difference).

Validation constraints through annotations in Entity:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\DateTime(message="createdAt must be valid DateTime string")
 */
private $createdAt;
```

Controller code for processing the form

```
 $user = new User();
 $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);
 $form->submit($request);
 if ($form->isValid()) {..}
```

If this field is not passed validation works.

Comment: Datetime is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Comment: what is the form of the date in your form?

Comment: The format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, is there a way to see the validation rule that fails? Even if I remove all constraints and pass something to the createdAt I get "ERROR: This value is not valid"

Comment: Looks like while the field is passed on the request it is not binding to the underlying object, any ideas?